# How to call javascript methods from native android when the app is closed or removed from background in Phonegap

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, background-service

Hi I am using local notifications and background service in my phonegap app. I want to run the java script functions in background service when the app is removed from background.I have checked some websites and also used some plugins, but didn't achieve.When I closed the app from background the service is running but the js functions are not getting called. I also read that if UI is not running in background then you cannot call js functions.
Any solution for this?Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways:

You can install a plugin which enables a background mode. But with this plugin you will get trouble if you want to have your app in a store and on the other hand, it could happen, that the device is closing the background mode.

The best way is, you have a resume listener in your app:

```
document.addEventListener("resume", onResume, false); 

function onResume(){
   // Your code
}
```

**Update:**

Have a look at the docs for further informations:
http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/dev/cordova/events/events.resume.html

Comment: Can you explain in detail? Where I have to place this document.addEventListener("resume", onResume, false);

Comment: Thanks Joerg Can I get any example app demo?